# Keyboard Touch Bar MacBook Pro late 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I bought the new MacBook Pro (with the Touch Bar) 4 months ago. The problem is I keep pressing by mistake "esc" and "siri" multiple times per day.

I thought it was my bad and I'd get used to it, but after 4 months I really think I have a problem or this Touch Bar is not well made in terms of User Experience.

Is there anything I can do to customise the Touch Bar avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not the only one.

I'm aware of people who have used [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) to modify the Touch Bar buttons and, in some cases, move the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to the right somewhat because they have the same problem.

BTT offers much more customisability then what Apple does via System Preferences. Also, you can associate buttons with your own scripts (using AppleScript) or use it to trigger Automator workflows.

You can download it for free to give it a try.

**Note:** I am not affiliated in any way with BTT.